# 404 On Using Azure Storage In Django Application

Tags: django, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to deploy a Django application on Microsoft Azure.

I am using nginx + gunicorn on a [Azure Virtual Machine](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/virtual-machines/). For serving static and media files, I have decided to use [Azure Blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-introduction) available in [Azure Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-introduction).

I am using the following library to integrate a Markdown + MathJax editor in my application - [django-mdeditor](https://github.com/pylixm/django-mdeditor/).

Now, this library comes with its own `JS` and `CSS` files. I am having no problem on using this library in the following scenarios -

- Local Development.
- Deployment on Heroku (production).
- Deployment on Azure Virtual Machine using nginx + gunicorn (production). In this case, I am serving the static files using nginx as mentioned in various tutorials, such as this [one](https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04_594319).

However, as soon as I shift to Azure Storage as my storage back-end. I am getting the following errors -

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (The specified blob does not exist.)
codemirror.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (The specified blob does not exist.)

codemirror.min.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (The specified blob does not exist.)

dialog.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (The specified blob does not exist.)

codemirror.min.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (The specified blob does not exist.)

matchesonscrollbar.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (The specified blob does not exist.)

dialog.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (The specified blob does not exist.)
```

Except for the above few files, the remaining static files are been fetched correctly!

Upon further investigation, I found out that all the above files are been fetched from the following script - https://github.com/pylixm/django-mdeditor/blob/master/mdeditor/static/mdeditor/js/editormd.js#L549

i.e. from the following code block -

```
.
.
editormd.loadCSS(loadPath + "codemirror/codemirror.min");
.
.
```

`loadPath` has been assigned `settings.path` in the script which is equal to the value of (afaik) `'./lib/'`.

`loadCSS()` is trying to fetch the file from the url -`https://edumate.blob.core.windows.net/static/mdeditor/js/libcodemirror/codemirror.min.js`

instead of `https://edumate.blob.core.windows.net/static/mdeditor/js/lib/codemirror/codemirror.min.js`.

Notice the missing `/` after `lib` in the first case. The URL generated is `.../libcodemirror/..` instead of `../lib/codemirror/..`!

The same is the case for all the the other `JS` and `CSS` files that are fetched using `loadCSS()` or `loadScript()` methods as shown above.

And the peculiar thing is, this deletion of `/` is only happening when using Azure Storage and not when using Heroku, nginx + gunicorn, or development server.

Any ideas on how to debug this?

Comment: Did you try to use `F12` key in Chrome to open the `Console` tab of Chrome DevTool to debug it?

Comment: The errors shown in my question are from the console only!

Comment: As of now, I am serving static files via Nginx only. Please help, as I would really love to shift to Azure Storage.